# What does 'did' refer to?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, comparative-constructions, do-support, comparative

> What is your favorite color? Do you often wear fashion items in that color? As for me, my favorite color is green, but I felt it did not go well with my skin tone, so I used to avoid wearing it. One day, I realized that green has many shades, so I experimented with various shades of green and eventually, I found that a deep green helps me look great. If you like a certain color, you can try various shades like I *did*, and find one that suits you.

In the last sentence, what does *did* refer to?

I thought it meant "tried various shades". But some argues that it means "experimented with various shades of green". So the question is whether the auxiliary did can refer to a verb phrase in a previous sentence.

Comment: It's a pro-form understood as _tried various colors_.

Comment: @BillJ So it can't mean "experimented with various shades"?

Comment: No: that information is too far back in the discourse. "Like I did" is a comparative statement in the sentence _If you like a certain color (then) you can try various shades like I did_.  Note that "then" can be inserted.

Comment: *You can try various shades like I did.* = *You can try various shades like I tried various shades.*  The phrase could further be shortened to, *You can do like I did.*

Answer (score 1):

The last "did" is referring to the speaker trying various shades of green (either clothing, or possibly makeup) until they found one they liked.

Comment: Thanks. I too thought it meant "tried various shades". But some argues that it means "experimented with various shades of green". So the question is whether the auxiliary _did_ can refer to a verb phrase in a previous sentence.

Comment: I believe it is specifically shades of green, as it wouldn't have otherwise made sense to make a point of realizing there are many shades of green. It's about the person realizing they can use their favorite color despite initially thinking it wouldn't go with their skin tone. The lead-up simply wouldn't make sense if the person had settled on using shades of red.

Comment: I'm asking if "did" can refer back to "experimented" in the previous sentence, as opposed to "tried" in the same sentence.

Comment: No, _did_ is used to avoid repeating the verb that has already been used _in the same sentence_.

Comment: To be precise, it's used to avoid repeating a **verb phrase** that has already been used in the same sentence.